# Spring FactoryBean used before it is configured?

Tags: spring

I have two FactoryBeans creating proxies for existing beans in the application context.

FactoryBeanA.getObject() is invoked as part of the singleton pre-instantiation, and it attempts to autowire the returned instance.

This autowiring needs a bean that is defined by FactoryBeanB, which has not yet been configured (had properties injected).

Can this be controlled in such a way, that I am sure both FactoryBeans are fully configured (properties injected) before any beans are attempted instantiated?

**Edit:**
Autowiring from FactoryBeanA objects have worked fine until I changed FactoryBeanB to require a property to be injected. After this change, I see autowiring for the A-bean try to invoke FactoryBeanB.getObject(), but this fails as properties has not yet been injected.

Comment: Have you tried it? Spring should be able to resolve the order of bean creation itself.

Comment: So to be clear, you have created two beans that implement the FactoryBean interface.

You need to autowire a value into A that is the result of the getObject method in B?

The problem with this picture is that the getObject method of a Factory Bean does not return a managed object, yet it appears that this is what you are trying to do.

Please clarify if I am not getting what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am unsure what is meant here by "managed bean". But previously the autowiring has worked just fine for the same setup. Only change is that FactoryBeanB now requires a property to be injected before it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was actually caused by my own mistake. FactoryBeanB was not configured properly as I thought.